# Version verification error for protobuff in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

When I run a python program which uses tensorflow I am getting the following error.

> [libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:61] This program requires
> version 3.6.1 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, but the installed
> version is 2.6.1.  Please update your library.  If you compiled the program
> yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol
> Buffers as your link-time library.  (Version verification failed in "bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.pb.cc".)
> terminate called after throwing an instance of
> 'google::protobuf::FatalException'
>
> what():  This program requires version 3.6.1 of the Protocol Buffer runtime
> library, but the installed version is 2.6.1.  Please update your library.   If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the
> same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  (Version
> verification failed in "bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework
> /tensor_shape.pb.cc".)
> Aborted (core dumped)

My protobuf version in python is:

```
$ pip3 show protobuf
Name: protobuf
Version: 3.6.1
Summary: Protocol Buffers
Home-page: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/
Author: None
Author-email: None
License: 3-Clause BSD License
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Requires: six, setuptools
Required-by: tensorflow, tensorboard, dynamicgem
```

```
$ protoc --version
libprotoc 3.6.1
```

Other details:

```
Operating System : Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Python 3.5.2
```

I also installed protobuf-cpp-3.6.1